# Does it conflict different class instances modifying and saving the same core data object?

Tags: core-data, save

In my app I have two instances of two different classes fetching the same core data object and grabbing a pointer to it in their respective properties. Then my two instances they both modify a different attribute in the core data object and save context at different moments. Is this going to create inconsistencies or merge conflicts in my app or will core data manage well this process? I've read about uniquing in the Core Data Programming Guide but I'm not sure I can extrapolate to my case the example they use.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a merge, it's just an update. There is only one instance of the managed object and multiple different pointers to it. If you check the address of the managed object instance you can verify this. So no, there are no issues (so long as you do all this on the same thread that owns the instance of course).

The uniquing you refer to relates to inserting multiple instances which both have the same unique identifier and is a different situation than you describe.